# What is the most efficient way to sort dictionaries inside of dictionaries by time (for a comment tree)?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, tree

I am attempting to sort a comment tree with a structure like so:

```
unsorted_dict = {
  1: [id, poster, time, comment, {
    2: [id, poster, time, comment, {
      3: [id, poster, time, comment]
    }]
  }],
  2: [id, poster, time, comment, {
      2: [id, poster, time, comment, {
        3: [id, poster, time, comment]
      }]
  }]
}
```

if `sort = newest`, i'd want to generate a sorted list/dictionary with the same structure as above but with each level sorted by time descending:

```
sorted_output = [
                 [1,'toplevel', 10:00pm, 'words...', [
                    [2,'secondlevel', 5:00pm, 'words...',
                       [3,'thirdlevel', '3:00pm', 'comment...'],
                       [4,'thirdlevel', '2:00am','comment']
                    ],
                    [5,'secondlevel', 4:00pm, 'words...', [
                       [6,'thirdlevel', '3:00pm', 'comment...'],
                       [7,'thirdlevel', '2:00pm','comment'],
                       [8,'thirdlevel', '1:00pm','comment']
                    ]
                  ],
                  [9,'toplevel', 9:00pm, 'words...', [
                    [10,'secondlevel', 7:00pm, 'words...',
                       [11,'thirdlevel', '4:00pm', 'comment...'],
                       [12,'thirdlevel', '3:00pm','comment']
                    ],
                    [13,'secondlevel', 6:00pm, 'words...', [
                       [14,'thirdlevel', '3:00pm', 'comment...'],
                       [15,'thirdlevel', '2:00pm','comment'],
                       [16,'thirdlevel', '1:00pm','comment']
                    ]
                  ]
                 ]
```

What is the most efficient way to sort each level of the dictionary and rebuild the final sorted list?

Note: the tree is capped at 3 levels

Bonus: Also, I would like to place the original posters comments at the top of each level, sorted by time.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why are you storing different types (semantically) of data in the same list? Relying on consistent list indices to store different pieces of data is somewhat easy to screw up. I would instead recommend dictionaries, like `{id:1, poster:"someone", time:"1:00pm", comment:"words", replies:[{...}, ...]}`

Comment: Also, I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for in the bonus. Where would these comments go and how would the be identified?

Comment: Do the keys in the original dict represent anything?

Comment: yes, keys in original dict are id of the top-level parents. so when processing query to build the unsorted_list i can add query entry to parent_dict[parent_id][child_dict]

Comment: re bonus: if poster == original poster: sorted(op_responses_list, by time) gets added to position[0] of whichever level it was found so they are always above "regular" replies, but are also sorted by time

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to sort this turning the dict in to a list, sorting, then recursing

```
def nested_sort(hsh):
    lst = list(hsh.iter_items()) # structure this however you want,e.g., build an object
                                #   with the subhash - [1,name, etc. {}]
    lst.sort()
    new_lst = []
    for sub_hsh in lst:  # get the subhash out however you structure it above
        new_lst += nested_sort(sub_hsh);  # recurse
```